# Overloading multiplication (addition, ...) operator in function class

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading

Sorry but I've got a complete noob-question. Have been trying to figure it out myself but I just can't seem to find the relevant information on google.

Let's put it like that, I have this piece of code:

```
class function
{
public:
    double (*f)(double x);
    function(double f(double x)): f(f){}
    double evalf(double x){
        return this->f(x);
    };
    function operator*(const function& other) const {
        return function(this->f*other.f);
    };
};
```

the problem is that the *-overload does not work and the issue is that he can't figure out how to multiply the two f's. Okay so here is what I did: I am calling the constructor using lambda expressions, for example

```
auto linear = [](double x){return x;};
```

and

```
auto blub = function(linear);
```

I figured out myself that

```
return function(this->f*other.f);
```

prolly won't work so what I tried was

```
auto mul = [&](double x){return this->f(x) * other.f(x);};
return function(mul);
```

but this ain't work either.
Funny thing is it seems to work outside of the function-class.

```
auto mul = [](double x){return linear*linear;};
```

works just fine.

Does anyone have a solution for me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered yourself, to multiply you need to use a lambda, but a lambda with a caputure can't be converted to a function pointer. So for what you did here

> ```
> auto mul = [&](double x){return this->f(x) * other.f(x);};
> return function(mul);
> ```

to work, you need to change `f` to

```
std::function<double(double)> f
```

Together you end up with

```
class function
{
public:
    std::function<double(double)> f;

    function(std::function<double(double)> f): f(f){}
    double evalf(double x){
        return f(x);
    };
    function operator*(const function& other) const {
        return function( [=]( double x ){ return this->f(x) * other.f(x); } );
    };
};
```

which then works, see 
**<kbd>[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc72792dcef1fa7e)</kbd>**